# PasteBin API scraper for new public pastes that appear at regular intervals

Tags: multithreading, io, perl, sqlite, curl

I'd like to optimize my code and get a better understanding of how I can perform the task I am doing better. I've only used Perl threads about 3 or 4 times now.

The purpose of my code block is to scrape the Pastebin API for every new public paste that appears at regular intervals using a crontab. Then search inside those new pastes for user defined regular expressions such as "google.com".  The paste is then saved to a sqlite DB for later viewing, and a notification is sent to a listening nodejs bot.

That being said, here is the code block I wish to have improved upon:

```
sub threadCheckKey {
    my ($url, $key, @regexs) = @_;
    my $fullURL = $url.$key;
    my @flaggedRegex = ();
    my $date = strftime "%D", localtime;
    my @data = ();

    my $thread = threads->create(sub {
        my $dbConnection = openDB();
        open(GET_DATA, "-|", "curl -s " . $fullURL . " -k") or die("$!");
        open(WRITE_FILE, ">", $key . ".txt") or die("$!");
        while(my $line = <GET_DATA>) {
            print WRITE_FILE $line;
            foreach my $regex(@regexs) {
                if($line =~ m/$regex/) {
                    if(!(grep(/$regex/, @flaggedRegex))) {
                        push(@flaggedRegex, $regex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        close(WRITE_FILE);
        close(GET_DATA);

        my $flaggedSize = @flaggedRegex;
        if($flaggedSize == 0) {
            #Uncomment below for debugging.
            #print "No user defined regex found\n";
            return;
        }

        open(READ_FILE, "<", $key . ".txt") or die("$!");
        while(my $line = <READ_FILE>) {
            push(@data, $line);
        }
        close(READ_FILE);

        my $inputData = join("\r", @data);
        my $flaggedReg = join(" | ", @flaggedRegex);
        my $updateRow = qq(UPDATE $tables[0] set data = ?, date = ?, regex = ? where pastekey = ?);
        my $updateRowPrepare = $dbConnection->prepare($updateRow);
        my $executeRowUpdate = $updateRowPrepare->execute($inputData, $date, $flaggedReg, $key);
        
        if($executeRowUpdate < 0) {
            print $DBI::errstr;
        }

        my $msg = qq(**Alert:** New paste found! The paste can be viewed via https://pastebin.com/$key - Regex Trigger: $flaggedReg);

       open(SEND_ALERT, "-|", "curl https://localhost:8051/bots/bot_service_id/alert -k --data '{\"text\":\"$msg\"}' -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -X POST") or die("$!");
        close(SEND_ALERT);

        $dbConnection->disconnect();
    });

    if($thread->is_running()) {
        sleep(2);
    }

    if($thread->is_joinable()) {
        $thread->join();
    }

    unlink $key . ".txt";
    return;
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason you don't [use scalars](https://perlmaven.com/open-files-in-the-old-way) for file operations?

Comment: @yuri No specific reason. I think it's just I was never taught best practices for Perl. I am going by old programming methods I self taught. The code above wasn't even how I originally coded it. I had to do some research after others made comments about insecure methods I was performing for the SQL calls and bad file handles.

Comment: To rephrase yuri's comment: You should avoid using global variables as file handles, an instead of use lexical variables. It's a simple drop-in replacement (`open(my $FH, ...)`, `<$FH>`, etc)

Comment: `if($thread->is_running()) { sleep(2); } if($thread->is_joinable()) { $thread->join(); }` should simply be `$thread->join;` though I don't see the point of creating a thread then simply waiting for it to end.

Comment: My main concerns are the improper code injections. Which begs the question of why shell out at all. I'll come back to that. /// The secondary concern would be the completely useless thread. There's no point to start a thread only to wait for it to finish. Furthermore, repeated thread creation is discouraged for performance reasons. It's generally recommended to reuse a pool of worker threads, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15018136/589924). (I believe modules exist that can reduce this.)

Comment: My suggestion is to avoid shelling out and to avoid threads by using [Net::Curl::Multi](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Curl::Multi)

Comment: Tip: No point in explicitly stringifying variables, as in `die("$!")`. `die` expects a string, so it will automatically stringify the value passed to it if necessary. That means you can simply use `die($!)`.

Comment: Tip: Arrays start out empty, so `my @a = ();` is a noisy way of writing `my @a;`.

Comment: Tip: What's the point of using an array if you're only going to use the first element (`$tables[0]`)?

Comment: Third major concern: You are using a local time for your timestamps. You should use UTC. 1) Simpler for the data reader. They just need to know the offset between their time zone and UTC, not between theirs and yours. 2) Using local time doesn't work well for places that use DST. Because of the jump back in the fall, you can't always reliably sort the fields by date, and you can't always reliably know what time something happened. 3) Won't suddenly break if you change data centre.

Comment: Note: The Net::Curl::Multi suggesetion assumes IO (not the regex matches) are the bottleneck.

Comment: Tip: Probably better to pass the regexs using a reference to an array (`threadCheckKey($url, $key, \@regexs)` and `my $url, $key, $regexs) = @_;`) rather than needlessly flattening and reassembling the array.

Comment: Tip: You should change `@flaggedRegex` to a hash. This would allow `if($line =~ m/$regex/) { if(!(grep(/$regex/, @flaggedRegex))) { push(@flaggedRegex, $regex); } }` to be reduced to `++$flaggedRegex{$regex} if $line =~ $regex;`. `my $flaggedSize = @flaggedRegex; if($flaggedSize == 0)` becomes `if (!keys(%flaggedRegex))`, and `@flaggedRegex` becomes `sort keys(%flaggedRegex)` or `grep { $flaggedRegex{$_} } @regexs` depending on whether you want to preserve order or not.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to initialize an array to an empty list
when declaring the variable:

```
my @flaggedRegex = ();
```

This is simpler and cleaner:

```
my @flaggedRegex;
```

---

Consider the following `open` line:

```
    open(GET_DATA, "-|", "curl -s " . $fullURL . " -k") or die("$!");
```

It is common to omit parentheses for built-in functions like `open` and `die`.

It is better to use a lexical variable instead of a global file handle.
Instead of `GET_DATA`, use `my $GET_DATA`.

Double quotes interpolate variables, whereas single quotes do not.
It is better to use single quotes around literal strings, like `-|`.

The `curl` command can be simplified as one string, eliminating quotes and concatenation operators:

```
"curl -s $fullURL -k"
```

It is good that you die with the error message, but you should give the user
more debugging information by using a unique message along with it.

Putting this all together:

```
open my $GET_DATA, '-|', "curl -s $fullURL -k" or die "curl $!";
```

Much of this also applies to the other `open` statements.

---

In the other `curl` command, it would be better to use the `qq` quote
operator as you have done elsewhere in the code.  That simplifies
the `curl` command string by avoiding the escaped double quotes:

```
open my $SEND_ALERT, '-|',
    qq(curl https://localhost:8051/bots/bot_service_id/alert -k --data '{"text":"$msg"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST)
    or die "curl2 $!";
```

---

There is no need for the scalar variable in the following code:

```
my $flaggedSize = @flaggedRegex;
if($flaggedSize == 0) {
    #Uncomment below for debugging.
    #print "No user defined regex found\n";
    return;
}
```

You should delete the commented-out code since it was probably
only added while you were developing the code.  The following is
much simpler:

```
return unless @flaggedRegex;
```

---

Simple `if` statements such as the following:

```
if($executeRowUpdate < 0) {
    print $DBI::errstr;
}
```

are arguably simpler as a single line, without the clutter of braces and parens:

```
print $DBI::errstr if $executeRowUpdate < 0;
```